# Dados demográficos do IBGE por bairros

Tags: api

Vi em alguns sites que são apresentados dados demográficos do IBGE por bairros. Pela análise que eu fiz utilizando a documentação da API do IBGE só consegui chegar no nível de município. Sei que de alguma forma é possível extrair essa informação, alguém teria alguma ideia?

Comment: Passa um link de uma página que apresente os dados demográficos organizados  por bairro, porque fiquei curioso e vi na API que a resolução máxima da consulta é 5 onde malha inclui somente os municípios.

Comment: https://www.redebrasilatual.com.br/blogs/blog-na-rede/2011/07/dados-do-censo-por-cidade-e-ate-por-bairro

Comment: Essa notícia foi publicada em 2011 e em algumas prefeituras aparecem as informações por bairros. Porém não consegui encontrar na plataforma deles nem uma API nem extração de dados por planilha https://www.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/cidade/secretarias/subprefeituras/subprefeituras/dados_demograficos/index.php?p=12758

Comment: Tenta incluir a consulta 'nivel=mn'.

Comment: obrigado @AugustoVasques pela informação, porém só estou conseguindo chegar no nível de município. Não no nível de bairros